# Writing a product function using guards in Haskell

Tags: function, haskell, if-statement, product

I need to write the function `product` in two ways:

1. Using Guards
2. Using if-then-else

So that the function return the product of m through n.

example:

`product 3 5`

returns 3*4*5 = 60

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? What went wrong? Please show us you've put a bit of effort in.

Comment: Please tag homework questions with [homework]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This sounds like a homework problem so instead of just dropping code on you, let's work through the problem:

**Type Signature**

Haskell is a functional language with strong typing so it is probably best to start by writing the type signature of our function.  Your example shows two integer arguments and an integer return value.  We code this as:

```
product :: Int->Int->Int
```

This reads as "`product` is a function that takes two `Int`s and returns an `Int`." (there are other more correct ways to read this but that is for another day)

**Recursion**

we are going to use a common pattern in Haskell.  Because we need to keep track of intermediate values in this case the partial product we will write a second function `product'` that will take an extra parameter, the running product.

```
product' :: Int->Int->Int->Int
product' accumulator current final = product' (accumulator*current) (current+1) final
```

At every iteration this will take the most recent accumulated value multiply by current and pass that as the new accumulator,  it will take current and add 1 to it passing it as the new current, and will pass final unchanged.  To get it started we write our original function:

```
product i f = product' 1 i f
```

or in points-free notation

```
product = product' 1
```

The problem is the `product'` code will loop forever.  We need a way to stop when we current is greater then final.

**Guards**

Rather then rewrite the book on guard patterns I'll [send you to the book](http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions#guards-guards). In short they let you a boolean before you do something.  We'll use them to stop our recursion.

```
product' :: Int->Int->Int->Int
product' accumulator current final 
    | current <= final = product' (accumulator*current) (current+1) final
    | otherwise = accumulator
```

So long as `current` is less than or equal to `final` we continue to recurse once it's not the final answer is in accumulator.

**If-Then-Else**

Guards can be replaced with `if` constructs (perhaps deeply nested) in a mechanical fashion.

```
product' :: Int->Int->Int->Int
product' accumulator current final = 
  if current <= final 
    then product' (accumulator*current) (current+1) final
    else accumulator
```

**Final Thoughts**

Don't write code like this.  There are a number of [wonderfully generic higher level function](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-List.html) that do just these types of things.  Here is just one better way to write product:

```
product i f = foldl (*) 1 [i..f]
```

Comment: I appreciate the effort of explaining, but you do realize that when people are asking for help on their homework, if you give them a complete implementation in addition to your explanation, it is unlikely that your explanation will be read with mindfulness.  Fortunately... I think... all your code examples are broken so this effect is -- at least altered somehow.

Comment: luqui, Thanks for the catch.  I've fixed the code.  The OP is just hitting this problem in November, which strongly implies that a survey course. The fact that Guards and If-then-else are two of the worst possible ways to write this function imply the teacher is just brushing by functional languages, and IMHO doing an awful job of it. I'll give out all the help I can in hope that Alyx might actually enjoy Haskell rather then find it hopelessly obtuse like most of his classmates will.

Comment: Why bother about accumulator? I'd think you only need it (together with a strictness annotation) when you are optimising for performance. `product current final = if current <= final then current * product (current+1) final else 1` should work as well and is simpler.